# best approach for setting hibernate/spring project

Tags: spring, hibernate, gwt

I have a project with spring and hibernate in GWT, 
I am using below applicationcontext.xml,
I was just looking for some best approach of making this file 
like all the annotated classes below i.e entity.user,  entity.secretQuestion and many more , they all get called when my application runs even if i don't need them , which i guess makes my application quite slow, 
so is it possible that only the class which i am calling is getting load in applicationcontext.xml and if yes then would it be a better approach as well ?

```
                 <bean id="sessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"> 
              <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
              <property name="annotatedClasses"> 
              <list> 
              <value>com.cricsite.persistence.entity.User</value>
              <value>com.cricsite.persistence.entity.SecretQuestion</value>


                </list> 
                </property> 
                </bean>
               <bean id ="ManagerAdmin" class= "com.persistence.MySQLRdbHelper">
                <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
                </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for something called "lazy loading"

Please take a look at these threads;

[Help needed with Spring/Hibernate Lazy-loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976888/help-needed-with-spring-hibernate-lazy-loading)

[What is lazy loading in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192242/what-is-lazy-loading-in-hibernate)

[how does spring allow for lazy-loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043976/how-does-spring-allow-for-lazy-loading)